# Using optim() or optimize() functions in R

Tags: r

I have been trying to use `optim()` or `optimize()` function to minimize the sum of absolute forecast errors.

I have 2 vectors, each of length 28, 1 containing forecast data and the other containing the actual data for the last 28 days.

The `fcst` and `act` vectors are here :-

```
fcst <- c(3434.23, 3434.23, 3232.4, 1894.63, 1989.23, 3827.71, 3827.71, 3827.71, 3434.23, 1984.42, 1894.63, 1989.23, 3827.71, 3827.71, 3827.71, 3827.71, 3625.88, 2288.11, 1989.23, 3434.23, 3434.23, 3434.23, 3434.23, 3232.4, 2288.11, 2382.71, 3827.71, 3827.71)

act <- c(3194.62, 3109.93, 2991.44, 1741.49, 1935.07, 3100.84, 3169.39, 3170.24, 2613.81, 1947.35, 1820.63, 1765.62, 3397.48, 3501.14, 3444.14, 3589.24, 3263.55, 2153.49, 2159.85, 3237.94, 3345.7, 3246.66, 3195.58, 3001.53, 2073.76, 2419.29, 3530.62, 3455.71)
```

I have created an objective function like so :-

```
fn <- function(fcst, act, par) {
sum(abs(act - (fcst * par)))}
```

Using the `optimize()` function like so :-

```
xmin1 <- optimize(fn, c(0.5, 1.5), fcst = fcst, act = act)
```

I get the correct value for 'par' - no problems.

```
> xmin1
$minimum
[1] 0.92235

$objective
[1] 3630.399
```

However, when I use the `optim()` function like so :-

```
xmin <- optim(par = c(0.1, 1.9), fn, fcst = fcst, act = act)
```

I get 2 values for par like this :-

```
> xmin
$par
[1] 0.9223822 0.9191707

$value
[1] 3623.823

$counts
function gradient 
      95       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

The question is why do I get 2 values for the single parameter 'par' using `optim()` function. Shouldn't I be getting only one (1) value as I do for the `optimize()` function?

Also, in either case, I get marginally different values for the parameter values depending upon the initial values of the parameter - should this be dependent upon the initial values when this objective function is essentially unimodal?

Best regards

Deepak Agarwal

Comment: This is a univariate optimization. Why give the 2 values for par?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are initializing the `par` object with 2 parameters and the default optimizer in `optim` so it thinks, for some strange reason, that it has to solve for 2 parameters (this has happen to me but i don't know why) just use 1 value en the `par` entry in the function and you will get the result you want.

```
xmin <- optim(par = 0.1, fn, fcst = fcst, act = act)
```

Comment: Thanks - the reason I gave 2 values (finite) was to provide the lower and the upper bounds - which apparently are required for the Brent method but not for other methods. It didn't work for the default method - Nelder-Mead and advised to use Brent - which I did with one (1) value and it worked OK! For optimize() function though, the upper and lower bounds are required and the result does get affected by the initial values - still don't get why though!

Comment: So you where defining the upper and lower bounds incorrecly, in `optim` ihere are the variables `lower` and `upper` for that and `par` is the initial value of the parameter you are trying to solve, it works for the default method Nelder-Mead it just sends a warning. IF you don't like warnings use `BFGS` which doesn't require bounds

Comment: Alegandro - using optim(), with par = 1  why does it not provide a value on default Nelder-Mead method - it provides an 'unreliable' warning and does not generate an output whether or not values for finite values for lower and upper are provided? Also, with other methods, why does it require finite values for these bounds as long as a finite initial value for the parameter has been provided for any method at all of course excluding Nelder-Mead?

Comment: About Nelder-mead reading Wikipedia it says that it is for multidimensional spaces so I guess that's why the warning pops. About the finite value of the bounds I just think  ` +/-Inf` is not a bound so just do unconstrained optimization, that's why you need finite values in the bounds. Note that this is just what I understand from optim I could be wrong

Comment: Great answer! Can you please take a look at this question if you have time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68280857/r-x-probs-outside-0-1 thanks

Comment: @stats555 it is already answer what do you expect me to do there?